# Trunc function a specfic column in SQL

Tags: sql, truncate

I am new with SQL and I am trying to run the below statement but its obviously not working. I need to truncate the "creat_DTTM" it has the date and time in it and I need to remove the time, so I can query off of the column. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Select *
  From icue.cmnct_trans
     WHERE Trunc(creat_DTTM) between ('19-feb-2018') AND  ('06-MAR-2018')
      AND  FAX_NBR = '201-553-7889'
      AND  RPT_PROV_NM ='CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA'
```

Comment: Try `trunc(creat_DTTM) between to_date('19-FEB-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('06-MAR-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm .

Comment: @wolfrevokcats - please submit your comment as an answer so it can be accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis Such trivia is not worth a full answer. May be the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: As an aside: If performance ever becomes an issue, and especially if you have an index on the date column, don't truncate. Instead, write the query as `where creat_dttm >= date '2018-02-19 and creat_dtm < date '2018-03-07`. (Note: < March 07, not 06 - think for a moment why that is.)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the Oracle DATE string literal format in these situations, which is `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

```
SELECT *
FROM icue.cmnct_trans
WHERE TRUNC(creat_DTTM) between DATE '2018-02-19' AND DATE '2018-03-06'
AND  FAX_NBR = '201-553-7889'
AND  RPT_PROV_NM ='CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA'
```

EDIT: forgot to include `DATE` keyword to force Oracle string literal

Comment: The default date format depends on the setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT. On your system it may be YYYY-MM-DD but on our system it's DD-MON-RR.

Comment: @BobJarvis Absolutely correct. I forgot the DATE keyword and have updated my answer. Using the updated answer, is not NLS_DATE_FORMAT dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! It worked like a charm . I did use the

trunc(creat_DTTM) between to_date('19-FEB-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('06-MAR-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')

and it ran perfectly! . Thank you